# d3.js: Hyphen gets mysteriously eaten when attaching class attribute to path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data that looks like this:

```
[   
{ key="0uFsTNpIPxs", values = [1] },
{ key="0wLp4mXvcgs", values = [1] },
...
]
```

I am binding this data to a d3.js streamgraph much like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060954). All working great.

On the transition I want to attach a class to each path that depends on the key in the data:

```
.attr('class', function(d) {
  return "ish-" + d.key;
});
```

This works most of the time, for all keys.  However sometimes, for keys starting with a zero it eats the hypen to leave e.g.`ish0uFsTNpIPxs` rather than `ish-0uFsTNpIPxs`

Any idea why this is happening, and what I can do about it?

Comment: `"ish-" + "0uFsTNpIPxs"` = `"ish-0uFsTNpIPxs"` - it seems as though your example might be evaluating `-0` to `0` for some reason (which would be fair enough), but why it's ignoring the string casting I'm not sure..

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm using Firefox 23.0.1

Comment: I've just tested `"ish-" + "0uFsTNpIPxs"` with 23.0 and it works fine for me.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff as I say, it works fine for me most of the time as well.  Certainly it's always worked as a one-off.  This bug occurs during the streamgraph transitions themselves, perhaps 50% of the time

Comment: Sounds like you're transitioning the class name as well. Make sure you attach it before calling `.transition()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff you are right, I was transitioning the class name.  It was my intention to transition to new classes, but hadn't realised that it would mash up the names and hence there might come a moment where to SmokeyPHP's point it would switch a -0 to 0.  I would accept this answer. Thanks for your help (and thanks for your great answers on d3 generally)

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably transitioning the class name as well as the other attributes. That is, code like

```
foo.transition().duration(1000)
   .attr("class", "foo");
```

will make the transition from the initial class name (probably empty) to "foo" -- with unpredictable results. This is almost certainly not what you want, although you could try to do some very clever stuff with this if you really wanted to.

To avoid this, simply attach the class name before the transition, i.e.

```
foo.attr("class", "foo")
   .transition().duration(1000);
```